# Making and using a library in Unix Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, libraries

I was trying some examples that i've found, but seems they are not working for me.

This is my system (uname -a): SunOS c-601 5.10 Generic_150400-59 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120

The example that im following is simple(https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shell_functions_library). This is the function library called myfuctions.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set variables 
declare -r TRUE=0
declare -r FALSE=1
declare -r PASSWD_FILE=/etc/passwd

##################################################################
# Purpose: Converts a string to lower case
# Arguments:
#   $1 -> String to convert to lower case
##################################################################
function to_lower() 
{
    local str="$@"
    local output     
    output=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'<<<"${str}")
    echo $output
}
##################################################################
# Purpose: Display an error message and die
# Arguments:
#   $1 -> Message
#   $2 -> Exit status (optional)
##################################################################
function die() 
{
    local m="$1"    # message
    local e=${2-1}  # default exit status 1
    echo "$m" 
    exit $e
}
##################################################################
# Purpose: Return true if script is executed by the root user
# Arguments: none
# Return: True or False
##################################################################
function is_root() 
{
   [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] && return $TRUE || return $FALSE
}

##################################################################
# Purpose: Return true $user exits in /etc/passwd
# Arguments: $1 (username) -> Username to check in /etc/passwd
# Return: True or False
##################################################################
function is_user_exits() 
{
    local u="$1"
    grep -q "^${u}" $PASSWD_FILE && return $TRUE || return $FALSE
}
```

And this is the script called functionsdemo.sh to call the functions:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Load the  myfunctions.sh 
# My local path is /home/vivek/lsst2/myfunctions.sh
. /home/vivek/lsst2/myfunctions.sh

# Define local variables
# var1 is not visitable or used by myfunctions.sh
var1="The Mahabharata is the longest and, arguably, one of the greatest epic poems in any language."

# Invoke the is_root()
is_root && echo "You are logged in as root." || echo "You are not logged in as root."

# Find out if user account vivek exits or not
is_user_exits "vivek" && echo "Account found." || echo "Account not found."

# Display $var1
echo -e "*** Orignal quote: \n${var1}"

# Invoke the to_lower()
# Pass $var1 as arg to to_lower()
# Use command substitution inside echo
echo -e "*** Lowercase version: \n$(to_lower ${var1})"
```

The example seems easy, but when i try it with different functions seems not so easy (i think i doing something worng).

This is my "library", called func.lib:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function cuenta() {
x=0
y=10
until [ $x -gt $y ]; do
echo "x = $x"
let "x++"
done
}



function compara() {

echo "Hola"
echo "Introduce un valor: "
read -r num1
echo "Introduce otro valor: "
read -r num2

if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ]; then
echo "$num1 es mayor que $num2"

elif [ $num1 -eq $num2 ]; then
echo "$num1 es igual a $num2"

else
echo "$num1 es menor que $num2"

fi
}


function read() {
read -p "Introduzca un dato : " dato1
read -p "Introduzca otro dato : " dato2

echo "Buenas tardes usted es un $dato1 $dato2"
}
```

And this is the .sh used to call the functions (testLib.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash


. /datos/usuarios/opersism/desarrollo/func.lib

cuenta

compara

read
```

And when i run it, i obtain this as exit:

```
c-601>> # ./testLib.sh
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
x = 8
x = 9
x = 10
Hola
Introduce un valor:
5
7
8
asd
qwe
^C
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
c-601>> #
```

It only executes the first function, the echos of the second fuction and does't realice the read of the second one.

Comment: check your code at https://shellcheck.net . Note that there is already an internal function named `read`, so it will be much safer to call your `myRead` or similar. Good luck.

Comment: True, i solved it, ty